# Why does this C reverse string function not work?

Tags: c

I'm confused why I get an empty string when I print out reversed. Printing out the character at each iteration seems to be working ok.

Output:

```
original string: testing
g
n
i
t
s
e
t
reversed:
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(char string[]) {
  int str_len = strlen(string);
  char reversed[20];

  int j = 0;
  for (int i = strlen(string); i>= 0; i--) {
    char tmp = string[i];
    reversed[j] = tmp;
    printf("%c\n", reversed[j]);
    j++;
  }
  reversed[j] = '\0';

  printf("reversed: %s", reversed);
}

int main (void) {
  char string[8] = "testing";
  printf("original string: %s", string);
  reverse_string(string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, your swap appears to be missing a step.

Answer (score 3):

`i` starts at `strlen(string)`, which points to the terminating `'\0'` character. That character is copied into position 0 in the `reversed` string, so any characters after that are not considered part of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = strlen(string); i>= 0; i--) {
    char tmp = string[i];
```

`string[strlen(string)]` is by definition always the string termination character `'\0'`. You have to start your loop at `strlen(string)-1`.